# PLS-00222: no function with name 'INFO_TYPE' exists in this scope

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to return a table of records in 2 situations:

1. using a function
2. using a anonymous block

When I am using the function, everything is working just fine but when I am trying to transform it into anonymous block i receive the above error.
Here are the codes:

For the function:

```
create or replace 
function get_info(p_city varchar2) return info_type_table
as
l_info info_type_table := info_type_table();
begin
    for i in (select  e.employeeid, 
                      e.lastname, 
                      c.customerid,
                      c.companyname,
                      o.orderid,
                      o.orderdate
              from  ntw_employees e
                inner join 
                    ntw_orders    o
                    on e.employeeid = o.employeeid
                inner join 
                    ntw_customers c
                    on o.customerid = c.customerid
              where e.city  = p_city)
    loop
        l_info.extend;
        l_info(l_info.count)  :=  (info_type(i.employeeid, i.lastname, i.customerid, i.companyname, i.orderid, i.orderdate));
    end loop;
    return l_info;
end;
```

And here is for anonymous block:

```
declare
type info_type is record 
(
    emp_no    number(3),
    lastname  varchar2(26),
    cust_no   varchar2(5),
    CO_name   varchar2(50),
    orderid   number(5),
    orderdate date
);

type info_type_table is table of info_type;

l_info info_type_table := info_type_table();
begin
    for i in (select  e.employeeid, 
                      e.lastname, 
                      c.customerid,
                      c.companyname,
                      o.orderid,
                      o.orderdate
              from  ntw_employees e
                inner join 
                    ntw_orders    o
                    on e.employeeid = o.employeeid
                inner join 
                    ntw_customers c
                    on o.customerid = c.customerid
              where e.city  = 'London')
    loop
        l_info.extend;
        l_info(l_info.count)  :=  (info_type(i.employeeid, i.lastname, i.customerid, i.companyname, i.orderid, i.orderdate));
        dbms_output.put_line('angajat = ' || i.employeeid);
    end loop;
end;
```

Can anyone explain me what is wrong in my anonymous block, please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function is (presumably) referring to an object type called `info_type`. Your anonymous block is using a record type. Record types do not have constructors. You have to assign each column individually, and have a record-type variable:

```
...
    l_info_rec info_type;
begin
    ...
    loop
        l_info.extend;
        l_info_rec.emp_no := i.employeeid;
        l_info_rec.lastname := i.lastname;
        l_info_rec.cust_no := i.customerid;
        l_info_rec.CO_name := i.companyname;
        l_info_rec.orderid := i.orderid;
        l_info_rec.orderdate := i.orderdate;

        l_info(l_info.count)  :=  l_info_rec;
        dbms_output.put_line('angajat = ' || i.employeeid);
    end loop;
end;
```

You could also have an explicit cursor and use the row that returns:

```
declare
    cursor c is select  e.employeeid, 
                      e.lastname, 
                      c.customerid,
                      c.companyname,
                      o.orderid,
                      o.orderdate
              from  ntw_employees e
                inner join 
                    ntw_orders    o
                    on e.employeeid = o.employeeid
                inner join 
                    ntw_customers c
                    on o.customerid = c.customerid
              where e.city  = 'London';

    type info_type_table is table of c%rowtype;

    l_info info_type_table := info_type_table();
begin
    for r in c
    loop
        l_info.extend;
        l_info(l_info.count)  :=  r;
        dbms_output.put_line('angajat = ' || r.employeeid);
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Or even with `bulk collect` straight into your table type:

```
declare
    cursor c is select  e.employeeid, 
              ...
              where e.city  = 'London';

    type info_type_table is table of c%rowtype;

    l_info info_type_table;
begin
    open c;
    fetch c bulk collect into l_info;
    close c;

    for i in 1..l_info.count loop
        dbms_output.put_line('angajat = ' || l_info(i).employeeid);
    end loop;
end;
/
```

... with a loop just to display the values from that table.

Comment: @mikcutu - re. your edit, the `extend` is still against the table type, not the record type. I ran all three versions in 11gR2 without errors, and all got the same output.

Answer (score 1):

Basically row-by-row processing is similar to slow-by-slow processing. Always try to use BULK collect where ever possible to avoid system performance glitch. Hope below snippet helps.

```
--Function with Bulk collect
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_info(
    p_city VARCHAR2)
  RETURN info_type_table
AS
  l_info info_type_table := info_type_table();
BEGIN
  SELECT e.employeeid,
    e.lastname,
    c.customerid,
    c.companyname,
    o.orderid,
    o.orderdate 
    BULK COLLECT  -- Using bulk collect for the performance
  INTO l_info
  FROM ntw_employees e
  INNER JOIN ntw_orders o
  ON e.employeeid = o.employeeid
  INNER JOIN ntw_customers c
  ON o.customerid = c.customerid
  WHERE e.city    = p_city;
  RETURN l_info;
END;

----Anonymous block with Bulk collect
DECLARE
type info_type
IS
  record
  (
    emp_no    NUMBER(3),
    lastname  VARCHAR2(26),
    cust_no   VARCHAR2(5),
    CO_name   VARCHAR2(50),
    orderid   NUMBER(5),
    orderdate DATE );
type info_type_table
IS
  TABLE OF info_type;
  l_info info_type_table; -- default constructor not required in record type case
BEGIN
  SELECT e.employeeid,
    e.lastname,
    c.customerid,
    c.companyname,
    o.orderid,
    o.orderdate
    BULK COLLECT 
    INTO 
    l_info
  FROM ntw_employees e
  INNER JOIN ntw_orders o
  ON e.employeeid = o.employeeid
  INNER JOIN ntw_customers c
  ON o.customerid = c.customerid
  WHERE e.city    = 'London';

  FOR I IN l_info.FIRST..l_info.LAST LOOP
  dbms_output.put_line('angajat = ' || l_info(i).employeeid);
  END LOOP;
END;
```